# I can't upload video background to website on local server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html5-video

I set couple_walk.mp4 in video file and wrote code below to upload it but does't work at all. I want to appear the video on header though.

```
<div class = "header-container">
        <div class = "video-container">
            <video preload = "true" autoplay = "autoplay" loop = "loop" volume = "0" poster = "pic.jpg">
                <source src=<%= video_tag("couple_walk.mp4") %> type = "video/mp4" >
            </video>
    </header>
```

and css codes for above is below

```
.header-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
}

.video-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

video {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.78;
    width: 100%;

}
```

any ides?

Comment: In your frontend, does the video link appears?

Comment: Not at all. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<video preload = "true" autoplay = "autoplay" loop = "loop" volume = "0" poster = "pic.jpg">
            <source src=<%= video_tag("couple_walk.mp4") %> type = "video/mp4" >
        </video>
```

with

```
<%= video_tag("couple_walk.mp4", controls: true, autobuffer: true, poster: "pic.jpg")
```

which will result like

```
<video src="/videos/couple_walk.mp4", controls: true, autobuffer: true, poster="/assets/screenshot.png"></video>
```

Ref: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html

Comment: So, what's the frontend content now? and as do you have video in videos/couple_walk.mp4 location?